# Hibernate criteria api 'Select in'

Tags: hibernate, subquery, hibernate-criteria

is it possible to create a 'select in'-query with the hibernate critiria api ?

Example :
I have two tables in a 1:n relation, company and department

```
select * from company c where c.id in (select company_id from department d 
where d.departmentname = 'HR' and d.location = 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use for this DetachedCriteria

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria= DetachedCriteria.forClass(Departament.class);
     subCriteria.add(Property.forName("departmentname ").eq("HR"));
     subCriteria.add(Property.forName("location ").eq("xyz"));
     subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("company_id "));

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Company.class);
     criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(subCriteria));
```