# Hibernate like query for escape character

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using **Mysql** database. I got stored data for certain columns with value of `a\"a`. I used following query to select but it failed:

```
select * from table_name where coloum_name like "%a\"%";
```

I spend some hours to find a query to select and the following one is working:

```
select * from table_name where coloum_name like "%a\\\\\\\\""%";
```

I'm using **hibernate** in my application, so I used:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("coloum_name","%a\\\\\\\\""%"));
```

but it's not working. Any possible way to select via criteria??

Comment: Check this out thoroughly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673508/using-hibernate-criteria-is-there-a-way-to-escape-special-characters

Comment: Thanks for response anakata. I already checked, but not suitable for me. i'm having '\"' char in column which i want to search.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097161/hibernate-criteria-api-select-in

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. Hope this will help for you.
http://levanhuy.wordpress.com/2009/02/19/providing-an-escape-sequence-for-criteria-queries/